# Dynamically Create Array and initialization of all element with minnus 1 (-1)

Tags: c++

I know how to create array Dynamically, but I wants to initialization of every element with negative one (-1)

Comment: Remove one of the language tags so we'll know if you want an answer for C or for C++.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` accepts a second parameter for the value to use to initialize elements:

```
std::vector<int> mydata(1000, -1); // 1000 elements, each initialized to -1
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` has a constructor that takes a size and a value to use as an initializer:

```
// create a vector of 10 integers with the value -1
std::vector<int> v(10, -1);
```